# ImageView Button Toggle inside listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, adapter, baseadapter

I have a List view of ringtones with a play image view in each row for each ringtone.

This is the view of it.

[image: Like this]

Now obviously when a user clicks on a play button it should switch to pause button.

Now I have a problem :

I click on a play button and it will turn into pause button, but in the meantime when I click on a play button from another row it takes two clicks until the second one turns into the pause button.

This is my code :

**Adapter**

```
    Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
    holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
    holder.playPause.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if (callback != null) {
                  callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
              }      
        }
    });
```

**Activity**

```
    @Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);
                if (paused) {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                paused=false;
                }else {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                 paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    };
```

I am already guessing the problem is in my condition

```
if(paused){
  }
```

I would be grateful if you can offer me a better logic

Comment: if i'm understanding right, you want to play/switch playback with one tap. to any other row right? for that you keep track of which row is playing right now .. stop the player for that row and play audio, change image of newly tapped row.

Comment: You made a good point .. Do you have any suggestion about  how to track the playing row ?I mean I have to first stop the playing song first and then play the new one .I know this has nothing to do with my original question but If you can prepare an answare for it and I will vote you up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using one `pause` field for all the rows so the first tap changes its status to `true` the second tap on the other row changes it to `false` and the sets the drawable

```
 product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause)
```

on the first row and the third tap works correctly.

you can define `pause` field for every `product` and inside if clause check the products  pause filed

```
if(product.pause){
    ...
    product.paused = false;
}else{
    product.paused = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slimier case in this what i did is i stream audio ringtones from url in a RecyclerView .. make a class variable as 
**private int oldPosition = -1;** , with this variable you'll keep track of which row is currently playing audio in RecyclerView

```
 @Override
public void onRecyclerViewChildItemClick(BaseRecyclerViewHolder holder, int resourceId) {
    super.onRecyclerViewChildItemClick(holder, resourceId);
    switch (resourceId) {
        case R.id.media_play_container:
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (oldPosition != -1)
                resetResources();
            if (oldPosition == position) {
                resetResources();
                oldPosition = -1;
                return;
            }
            updateViewAtPosition(false, false); // update old selected view
            oldPosition = position;     // update position
            BaseRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (BaseRecyclerViewAdapter) getRecyclerView().getAdapter();
            AudioItem item = (AudioItem) adapter.getItemAt(oldPosition);
            String url = item.getAudioPreviewUrl();
            // if url is valid show progress and play
            if (AppUtils.ifNotNullEmpty(url)) {
                updateViewAtPosition(true, false);
                playRingtone(url);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.iv_media_favorite:
            break;
    }
}
```

This method updates old row that is playing
**updateViewAtPosition(false, false);**

```
private void updateViewAtPosition(boolean isLoading, boolean isPlaying) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = getRecyclerView();
    if (recyclerView == null || oldPosition == -1)
        return;
    BaseRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (BaseRecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null)
        return;
    AudioItem item = (AudioItem) adapter.getItemAt(oldPosition);
    item.setPlaying(isPlaying);
    item.setLoading(isLoading);
    adapter.update(oldPosition, item);
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(oldPosition);
}
```

// reset media player 
resetResources();

```
private void resetResources() {
    resetMediaPlayer();
    resetViewResources();
}

private void resetMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.caughtException(e);
    }
}

private void resetViewResources() {
    if (oldPosition == -1)
        return;
    updateViewAtPosition(false, false);
}
```